# How to communicate to an android device without a USB connection. Possibly via serial port

Tags: android, python, automation, serial-port, adb

I would like to know of ways to communicate to an android device using anything other than usb(which is the traditional way to do it via adb).

I know that serial console is possible but is there a less complicated way to send commands over serial using python? If not I would be very interested in knowing ways to automate sanity tests on a device and these tests would require USB to be disconnected (Yes, for suspend resume tests).

I will check adb documentation for this but with what little knowledge I have adb communication is quite difficult over serial when USB is not connected.

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: unless you've got an android device with an actual serial port, usb (or wifi/cellular) is ALWAYS going to be necessary.

Comment: You can connect to your device using wifi if your device is rooted. Search "wifi adb" on google play.

Answer (score 1):

You can connect to your device using wifi, even if your device isn't rooted.

In [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3623727/1003032) is explained how to do that.

The data transmission is a little bit lower, but for small apps, and small amount of data it will work perfectly.

Comment: +1 ... but you might want to mention how he can do it without rooting (you just need to enter developer mode ... pretty much every phone has it you just need to figure out how to enable it)... edit nm .. theres even easier ways highlighted in that response :P I just saw the rooted bit